# Perl processing log file

Tags: linux, perl, logging

I want to create a perl script that processes log files in linux. The ideea is to sort the "interesting" lines from the others. My plan is this:
- make a temp copy of the log file (because it is constantly written)
- search for the "interesting" lines (keywords)
- copy them in another file "log.processed" 
- send that file over the e-mail to me. (this part i think will be done by cron)

Untill now i have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;

copy("/home/hq-asa.log","/home/hq-asa.temp") or die "Copy failed $!";
$NewLog     = "/home/hq-asa.processed";
our $search = "keyword1|keyword2|";
my $TempLog = "/home/hq-asa.temp";

open (my $LogFile, "+<", $TempLog) or die "Could not open log temp file $!";
qx(touch $NewLog);
open ($newlog, "+<", $NewLog) or die "could not open new log file $!";
foreach $line (<$LogFile>) {
    if (($line =~ m/$search/) or ($line eq $search))  {
        print $newlog $line;
    }
}
close($LogFile);
close($newlog);
unlink "/home/hq-asa.temp";
```

Don't judge, i am a newbie.
The problem is that if i want this script to be run every hour  for example it will process again and again all the original log file. Can i inser a "bookmark" in the original log file and tell this script to search for the last one and continue from there? Or how should this be done?

Comment: why did you comment out `use strict;` ?

Comment: Don't want to keep you from having some fun and learning, but Logwatch does exactly what you describe: http://www.logwatch.org/

Comment: because i was getting errors and warnings because not all variables are defined as "my" or "our". it is for testing purposes only. I will uncomment that line later when the script works.

Comment: @ManeaDragosh No, no, no, you got it backwards. `use strict` helps make your script work, not the other way around, whatever weird way that would be? (Using strict on a script that already "works"?)

Comment: Thank you for LogWatch :). I will continue to build this script, for fun/learning but i think i will use it :).

Comment: If you're doing it for learning, please realise that commenting out use strict was a mistake.  With the exception of simple one liners, or horrible, complex legacy code (maybe), you should always use strict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write out a status file containing the [line number](http://p3rl.org/var#%24INPUT_LINE_NUMBER) where you left off. When you want to resume processing, first read the status file and skip the number of lines.

Comment: Ok, that sounds a good ideea. But how do i know where i left off? How do i find the last line number?

Comment: That's a hyperlink there in my answer. Do follow it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`tell()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tell.html) to get what you call a "bookmark" (the offset in the file) and [`seek()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html) to go back to that place.

Also saving the inode number (the result of `(stat $file)[1]`) with the bookmark might be helpful to ensure that the file has not been replaced by another one (think about rotating logs with `logrotate`).